# Laravel - filter through relationship

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have Product and Prices models, so that Product can have multiple prices. It is 'one to many' relation. I need to filter products by min and max price. When there will be price-min value in request, it will show only those products that all its prices are >= price-min.

How can I build a query for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In model Product create relationship

```
public function prices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Price');
    }
```

In your controller add this:

```
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Price;

function filterProductsByPrice($priceMin, $priceMax = null)
{
    $query = Product::query();

    // Filter products by minimum price
    $query->whereHas('prices', function ($query) use ($priceMin) {
        $query->where('value', '>=', $priceMin);
    });

    // Optionally, filter products by maximum price
    if ($priceMax !== null) {
        $query->whereHas('prices', function ($query) use ($priceMax) {
            $query->where('value', '<=', $priceMax);
        });
    }

    // Retrieve the filtered products
    $filteredProducts = $query->get();

    return $filteredProducts;
}
```

Or instead $query=Product::query(), you can call

```
$products=Product::whereHas('prices', function ($query) use ($priceMin) {
        $query->where('value', '>=', $priceMin);
    }))->get();
```